# Online shopping cart with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am using Laravel and [Moltin/Cart](https://github.com/moltin/cart) to build the cart system for an online store. So far, I have managed to integrate the Cart system and continue with paypal. 
Though, in my controller I have a constructor that prevents the user from viewing, adding or removing items from the cart unless he is authenticated.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('postAddtocart', 'getCart', 'getRemoveitem')));
}
```

In order to make paypal to work I had to add several hidden inputs in my view that get the necessary values and passing them to paypal's paying page, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="office@shop.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="eCommerce Store Purchase">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{ Cart::total() }}">
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="{{ Auth::user()->firstname }}">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="{{ Auth::user()->lastname }}">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}">

{{ HTML::link('/', 'Continue Shopping', array('class'=>'btn btn-default')) }}
<input type="submit" value="Checkout with Paypal" class="btn btn-primary">
```

The problem is that the user shouldn't be logged in to view, add or remove items from the cart, but to be asked for a login when the submit button is clicked. If I remove the filters from my constructor then, I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error because of the hidden inputs that make use of the Auth class. I have tried to add a blade if auth::check condition but that wasn't the solution. Any suggestions?

**Answer**

This did the trick:

```
@if(!Auth::check())

      {{ HTML::link('users/signin', 'Sign in to pay', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) }}

@else
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="{{ Auth::user()->firstname }}">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="{{ Auth::user()->lastname }}">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}">

{{ HTML::link('/', 'Continue Shopping', array('class'=>'btn btn-default')) }}
<input type="submit" value="Checkout with Paypal" class="btn btn-primary">
@endif
```

Also, I removed the filters from the constructor and changed the redirection in the sign in function, so that it redirects to the previously accessed page.

**Using a session variable to hold the previously visited url**

In order to go back to the previously visited page you need to use `session::put`.

So, in the getSignin function add:

```
Session::put('previous_url', URL::previous());
```

And in the postSignin function you need to retrieve the previous_url variable, which is stored in the session, like so:

```
if ( Session::has('previous_url') )
{
     $url = Session::get('previous_url');
     Session::forget('previous_url');
     return Redirect::to($url);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I am working on the same ecommerce laravel tutorial and doing the same logic. Where exactly and how did you do the redirect intended to where the page goes back to cart after signin. I cannot seem to get it correct. thanks.

Comment: You could also do that redirect trick with laravel's "Redirect::intended('/')"  after successful login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about replacing the checkout button with a sign in button and then redirect to the cart checkout again?